# Is there a stateless version of the JPA EntityManager?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, stateless

Hibernate has a [Stateless Version of its Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html): Does something similar exist for the JPA EntityManager? I.e. an EntityManager that does not use the first level cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not part of the JPA API or spec. Individual implementations may allow disabling the L1 cache. DataNucleus JPA, the one I have used, does allow this

Answer (score 8):

From JPA point of view:

- `javax.persistence.EntityManager` stands for *1st level cache* (persistence context, transactional cache)
- `javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory` stands for *2nd level cache* (shared cache)

A given persistence provider may implement additional caching layers. Additionally JDBC Driver API may be treated as low-level cache for storing columns/tables and caching connections/statements. It's however transparent to JPA.

Both [javax.persistence.EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) and [org.hibernate.StatelessSession](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) offer similar APIs.

You cannot disable 1st level cache with EntityManager beacuse these two things are equivalent. You can however:

- skip 1st level cache by using `createQuery`, `createNamedQuery`, `createNativeQuery` for querying and bulk updates/deletes (the persistence context is not updated to reflect their results). Such queries should be executed in their own transaction thus invalidating any cached entities, if any. Transaction-scoped entity manager (means stateless) should be used as well.
- disable 2nd level cache by setting up `<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>` in persistence.xml or `javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode` in properties

Answer (score 0):

On an interface point of view, RDBMS usually respect the [ACID constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), a *stateless* option would be very specific. I guess this is the reason why Hibernate proposes this feature but not the specification.

To disable the cache, you have implementation-specific configurations ([here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F) is the doc for EclipseLink). The [@Cacheable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html) annotation (JPA 2.0) at the entity level is standard.

But if you would like to perform bulk operations, this would not do the job. Anyway, such a behavior would be implementation-specific.

Comment: FWIW The annotation you mention is for the L2 cache not L1